# Hardfault exception on stm32f7 arm microprocessor at RTX thread creation

Tags: c, stm32, arm, rtos

I'm running a simple RTX thread program as follows. The problem is when it's running on STM32F7 DISCOVERY BOARDv through debug interface, it seems right after running the `osThreadCreate (osThread(Thread), NULL);` the program jumps to hardfault interrupt. It used to run fine before.

```
void Thread (void const *argument);         
osThreadId tid_Thread;                                   
osThreadDef (Thread, osPriorityNormal, 1, 0);          

int Init_Thread (void) {

  tid_Thread = osThreadCreate (osThread(Thread), NULL);
  if (!tid_Thread) return(-1);

  return(0);
}
```

and my clock configuration is as follows:

```
static void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;

  /* Enable HSE Oscillator and activate PLL with HSE as source */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_OFF;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 25;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 432;  
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 9;
  if(HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* activate the OverDrive to reach the 216 Mhz Frequency */
  if(HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2);
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;  
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;  
  if(HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_7) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

and this is the handler my program jumps to(at stm32_746xx.s):

```
HardFault_Handler\
PROC
EXPORT  HardFault_Handler          [WEAK]
B       .
ENDP
```

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Keil uvision version 5.17

Comment: "It used to run fine before." - before *what*? What is different between now and "before" (other than the HardFault)?

Comment: A HardFault is raised, because you probably access invalid memory somewhere (e.g. a null pointer or a invalid hardware register). You can try to recover the context by inspecting the stack. See for example [this link](http://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html). It's written for FreeRTOS, but most of it applies to ARM ABI in general. By that you can see which function and which access caused the HardFault and try to debug it.

Comment: The only difference is that I updated the CMSIS and STM32 HAL libraries.

Comment: It seems to jump to hardfault after running: '    if ((free = (void **)__ldrex(&((P_BM) box_mem)->free)) == 0U) ' more specifically.

Comment: I ran the exact code on STM32F429 with no problem at all!

Comment: Would you mind posting your linker script too? I have a sneaking suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

If you use stm32cube classic for configuration, the problem might be by MPU_Config function. I just switched the `MPU_InitStruct.IsShareable = MPU_ACCESS_SHAREABLE;` line with `MPU_InitStruct.IsShareable = MPU_ACCESS_NOT_SHAREABLE;`. This is about sharing memory by several processes or threads but I don't know the details. if your program runs on one thread or you handle the memory access by yourself, you can make the code run by that change.